# Different ways of creating subsets

Tags: probability

I'm trying to answer the following excercise:

In a Math university course there are 3 available rooms: Room1 and Room2 sit 50 students, Room3 sits 100 students. To follow the introduction to probability course 200 students are divided in 3 groups of 100, 50, and 50 students.

1. In how many ways can you create the 3 groups?
2. In how many ways can you assign the students to the rooms?
3. Anna and Louise want to be in the same group to help each other study, but they hope to not be in the same group as Tom. What is the probability that their wish will happen?

For 1) I thought the answer would be a permutation of a multiset so $\frac{200!}{100!50!50!}$ but I'm a bit stumped on 2) and 3), any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct for the first one, but I invite you to think about it as the number of ways you can put $100$ people in the first room from an original group of $200$ times the probability that you can put $50$ people in the second room when picking from the remaining $100$. Again you are correct, but this is easier to visualize.

For the second question the answer should be the same unless you are now ignoring the statement about how many students should be in each room. In which case, the number of ways is $3^n$

Finally, the probability that Anna and Louise are in the same room is $\frac{1}{3}$ but they also don't want to be in the same room as Tom which implies he is one one of the other rooms so multiply the first value by $\frac{2}{3}$ and you get $\frac{2}{9}$.